# How can Skarner increase the distance he can pull an Impaled champion?

Tags: league-of-legends

Besides Movement Speed effects, I would like to know a list of any ways Skarner can move/be moved (using the help of his allies, not enemies) while his ultimate, Impale is active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thresh is the only champion that can relocate his allies at the moment, so I scoured Youtube for Dark Passage/Impale combination. Here is the result.

So I think I can safely say that this combination does work. Have fun dragging your enemies under tower from a great distance!

(There are also a large number of champions that can grant movement speed buffs, but that doesn't sound like what you're looking for.)

Edit: With the release of Kalista, another method has arisen, and it works!

[image: KalistaGif]

Edit 2: Electric Boogaloo: Neither Bard's Magical Journey, nor Tahm Kench's Abyssal Journey work. I *think* that Kench's Devour does work, but I'm having difficulty finding proof.

Comment: Ey mate, Im going through some of my past answers and questions, and - for the giggles - would you be arsed to add Bard to the list if you find any proof? Im curious if you can drag people through his tunnel thing.

Comment: @user1337 Skarner can't drag enemies through a bard portal, from the digging I've done this morning.

Comment: Much appreciated.